# Dynamically loaded javascripts adding extra quotes for object values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-localizer

I am loading JavaScript object dynamically by injecting script.

```
(function (jqL) {
 jqL.addResource({
    ResKey1:'JS English Res',
    ResKey2:'JS English res2',
  });
 })(jqueryLocalization);
```

I am filling this object to jquery custom plugin variable using below script -

```
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
  // Global Variable to Store Key Values like Dictionary
  jqL.Resources[key] = value;
  // Printing value properly without any extra quotes - 'JS English Res'
  alert("VAl " + jqL.Resources[key]);
 });
```

Outside this block when I am trying to access the values it adds extra quotes, comma to the value. See the console logs.

[image]

When I accessed this object in console, it shows the values with extra quotes and comma.

[image]
Did you faced such issues? Any suggestion what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was issue with internal condition which was failing always outside $.each(). That's why it was working inside $.each() and not outside.